# Is there a way to create a "dual percentage" scatter plot using vegalite?

Tags: html, graph, vega-lite

[I wish to make something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSaPg.png)
[I have data in a csv format found here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b-onbon/FIT3179/main/A2/Data/Retention_Rate.csv)
I'm not sure what to use to create it using vegalite, my current attempt has the graph appear but the data is not plotted :(
Any help or advice would be appreciated!!

I don't know if it's valid to convert the data (Retention column) as percentage values rather than use them as numerical values but I have tried to do that.
I would also like to use a selection menu filter for the year, where it shows all the points for 2021 and 2022 at the start, and highlights the data of the selected year after user selection (while leaving the other year's data at a lower opacity) and have attempted that as well.

This is my code so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 400, 
  "height": 300,
  "title": "Secondary Retention Rate",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b-onbon/FIT3179/main/A2/Data/Retention_Rate.csv"
  },
  "params": [
    {
        "name": "select_year",
        "bind": {
            "input": "select",
            "options": ["2021", "2022"],
            "labels": ["2021", "2022"],
        "name": "Select Year"
        }
    } 
],
"transform": [
    {
      "filter": {"field": "Gender", "equal": "Male"}
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Percentage",
      "as": "diagonal" 
  },
  {
    "filter": {"field": "Gender", "equal": "Female"}
  },
  {
    "calculate": "datum.Percentage",
    "as": "end" 
}
],
"layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"field": "Gender", "equal": "Male"}}
      ]
    },
    {
        "mark": {"type": "point", "filled": true},
        "transform": [
          {"filter": {"field": "Gender", "equal": "Female"}}
        ]
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "black"},
        "transform": [
          {"filter": {"field": "Gender", "equal": "Male"}}
        ],
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "diagonal", "type": "quantitative"},
          "y": {"field": "end", "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      }
    ],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Retention",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Males %",
      "scale": {"domain": [50, 100]}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Retention",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Females %",
      "scale": {"domain": [50, 100]}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Gender",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"range": ["#9370db", "#87a96b"]}
    }
    }
  }
```

[This was the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFhWD.png)
[Link to vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-29ghsIsZDDg2xAjKQLLZHLB7t5UoFQsEIpA-sD0rlLuVUfViI1xfc5YFlerdlr9Yi3KbcBbbjbHa7PfZnMbnuHPtHfolUuD07DEeQNjpC5jJZXoDXpIPL6UzkENk7CYVEoHLI8mQgVlT37c8h3dX0xVvIMQBDGcQBVF952DWRnDUfoyC9AAPL0RzHfCnTORJLCrUlpzmaIrFIV0QA8UirzHHMaPXdB6KsRiaGY9V6SUD8NzrIJpVwth8NkQiBRIy9EJAGYSnmCJvzsPi6DCQSbU7axSUwuAIC8ABSCJoCjAU1DYPp5DBMR9DaPQFw7NilOvdBVLmOQNNorT5QY3TmMsQy7CfVVTIspQrJfGy7KQfpjichQXJ0Nz-zYQD+QQrzx2Q-yeKJOz+hdWK4wuUAmQzMEQAAYi6UwOh0NQmAieqAA4OiQLoADZ2rc9UgA)

Comment: Data: 404: Not Found
Please update your question with valid data and explain the X Y values for a given point.